# Splitting Workbook into separate workbooks including all tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I looked at Bhaskar's code on the post located here ([VBA code to split an excel file into multiple workbooks based on the contents of a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062478/vba-code-to-split-an-excel-file-into-multiple-workbooks-based-on-the-contents-of))
and have modified it to the point where it recognizes the field I need the workbooks split on but I am getting a variable not defined error at the following section

For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows

I appreciate any help you could provide

I have included the code.

```
Option Explicit
Dim personRows As Range     'Stores all of the rows found

'Split data into separate columns baed on the names defined in
'a RepList on the 'Names' sheet.
Sub SplitSalesData()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim p As Range
Dim counter2 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
counter2 = 0
i = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' in my case i am generating new excel based on every 8 reacords from begining. You can simplyfy this logic based on your need.

        For Each p In Sheets("Source").Range("AM1") ' Give the name of your input sheet and column
            If i = 0 Then                              ' We are starting, so generate new excel in memeory.
                Workbooks.Add
                Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
                ThisWorkbook.Activate
            End If
            WritePersonToWorkbook wb, p.Value
            i = i + 1   ' Increment the counter reach time
            If i = 8 Then   ' As my need is after processing every 8 uniqe record just save the excel sheet and reset the processing
                counter2 = counter2 + 1
                wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\salesdata_" & CStr(counter2)   ' save the data at current directory location.
                wb.Close
                Set personRows = Nothing  ' Once the process has completed for curent excelsheet, set the personRows as NULL
                i = 0
            End If
        Next p

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wb = Nothing
End Sub

'Writes all the data rows belonging to a RepList
Sub WritePersonToWorkbook(ByVal SalesWB As Workbook, _
                      ByVal Person As String)
Dim rw As Range
Dim firstRW As Range

For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows - ***ERROR IS HERE***
    If Not Not firstRW Is Nothing And Not IsNull(rw) Then
        Set firstRW = rw  ' WE want to add first row in each excel sheet.
    End If
    If Person = rw.Cells(1, 5) Then  ' My filter is working based on "FeederID"
        If personRows Is Nothing Then
            Set personRows = firstRW
            Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
        Else
            Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
        End If
    End If
Next rw
personRows.Copy SalesWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) ' Adding data in Excel sheet.
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I should say what I am trying to do. I am looking to make a separate copy of the workbook for each rep including all of the tabs and if the tabs contain pivot tables (a few of them do) refresh the pivot tables to reflect just that reps data

Comment: `UsedRange` is never defined as a variable.  If you mean the used range of a specific worksheet, you need to tell it what worksheet you're interested in: `Sheets(1).UsedRange` or `Sheets("Sheetname").UsedRange`

Comment: `For each p in Sheets("Source").Range("AM1")` is just one cell. Do you mean that there's a range, with sheet names, and you want to get that range, and loop through those names?

Comment: yes the column AM in sheet "Source"  is where the reps names are and use that list to determine the unique names and create a separate workbook for each name

Comment: ok I change the range to      ' For Each p In Sheets("Source").Range("AM:AM")' to try and have it look at the whole column

Comment: and I changed the UsedRange section to     For Each rw In Sheets("Source").UsedRange.Rows

Comment: and the error I get now is at the very bottom    Runtime Error 91  Object Variable or With Block Variable not set and it highlights row     personRows.Copy SalesWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) ' Adding data in Excel sheet.

Comment: That's because personRows = Nothing, which in turn is because `Person = rw.Cells(1, 5)` never became True.